# How to wait fetch in each-loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, kendo-ui

I want for each item to bring data from server then create a combo box containing this data. What is going on now is I got 3 combo boxes with same data.

I have this code:

```
self.CollectionTest.each(function(item, index) {
    if (item.attributes.QuesAnswerType == 7) {
        self.dtype = item.attributes.QuesAnswerValue_Para;
        self.dropdowncollection = new QuestionaireDetailsCollection;
        self.dropdowncollection.fetch({
            reset: true,
            url: 'api/Variables/getPara',
            data: $.param({ type: self.dtype }),
            success: function() {
                self.dropdowndataSource = new kendo.Backbone.DataSource({
                    collection: self.dropdowncollection,
                });

                var cbid = "cb" + item.attributes.Id;
                $('<input id="' + cbid + '" dataTextField: "Name" dataValueField: "Id" data-bind="value:QuesDetAnswer"/>')
                    .appendTo("#divrb" + item.attributes.Id)
                    .kendoDropDownList({
                        dataTextField: "Name",
                        dataValueField: "Id",
                        dataSource: self.dropdowndataSource,
                        autoBind: true,

                    });
            } // end of success
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it seems that the problem is that you are always assigning values to the `self` object.
The code of the success method is executed asynchronously.
Therefore the values of the `self` object get overridden in every success method call.

I would recommend trying to get rid of the `self` reference in the success method. Something like

```
var dropdowncollection = new QuestionaireDetailsCollection;
dropdowncollection.fetch({reset: true, url: 'api/Variables/getPara', data: $.param({ type: self.dtype }), success: function () {
    var dropdowndataSource = new kendo.Backbone.DataSource({
        collection: self.dropdowncollection,
    });

    var cbid = "cb" + item.attributes.Id;
    $('<input id="' + cbid + '" dataTextField: "Name" dataValueField: "Id" data-bind="value:QuesDetAnswer"/>')
    .appendTo("#divrb" + item.attributes.Id)
    .kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "Name",
        dataValueField: "Id",
        dataSource: dropdowndataSource,
        autoBind: true,
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, ur suggestion worked ... thanks and best regards

Answer (score 0):

You're approaching the problem the wrong way. Instead of using all of Backbone as it should, you're trying to hard-code everything in callbacks. This is [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/).

What you're trying to do is to render a collection. There's a lot of questions about rendering list/collection on Stack Overflow, here's some of my own answers which have a list rendering as an example:

- [Rendering Backbone collection from XML data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40724956/1218980)
- [Detailed explanation of Backbone using a list example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40405934/1218980)
- [Another list example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40004457/1218980)

I'll try to demonstrate how to fetch each before rendering.

Put the url once where it belongs, into the collection class.

```
var QuestionaireDetailsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'api/Variables/getPara',
});
```

Wrap the item rendering logic into a view

```
var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template('<input id="cb<%= Id %>" dataTextField="Name" dataValueField="Id" data-bind="value:QuesDetAnswer"/>'),
    id: function() {
        return "divrb" + this.model.id;
    },
    initialize: function() {
        // let the item view handle the collection
        this.collection = new QuestionaireDetailsCollection();

        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.onSync);

        this.collection.fetch({
            reset: true,
            data: $.param({ type: this.model.get('QuesAnswerValue_Para') }),
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$input = $(this.template({ Id: this.model.id }))
        this.$el.html(this.$input);

        this.$input.kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: "Name",
            dataValueField: "Id",
            dataSource: this.dropdowndataSource,
            autoBind: true,
        });
        return this;
    },
    onSync: function() {
        this.dropdowndataSource = new kendo.Backbone.DataSource({
            collection: this.collection,
        });

        this.render();
    },
});
```

Also wrap the list rendering in a view

```
var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.childViews = [];
        this.quesAnswerType = 7;
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render);
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.empty();

        // filter the models before rendering
        _.each(this.collection
            .where({ 
                QuesAnswerType: this.quesAnswerType
            }), this.renderItem, this);
        return this;
    },
    renderItem: function(model) {
        var view = new ItemView({ model: model });
        this.childViews.push(view);
        this.$el.append(view.render().el);
    },

    cleanup: function() {
        // avoid memory leaks
        _.invoke(this.childViews, 'remove');
        this.childViews = [];
    }
});
```